# How to count elements of a column ignoring the null values ​in Laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to count all the elements of a column with Query Builder and I can't exclude null values ​​from the count, I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as ttg, inc_padre'))
                 ->where('inc_padre', '<>', null)
                 ->groupBy('inc_padre ')
                 ->get();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as ttg, inc_padre'))
    ->whereNotNull('inc_padre')
    ->groupBy('inc_padre')
    ->get();
```

For find all counts where inc_padre is not null

```
$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->whereNotNull('inc_padre')
    ->count();
```

Comment: try with `->groupBy('inc_padre')`, deleted space

Comment: There is a space after `inc_padre` delete that. Change `inc_padre ` to this `inc_padre`. BTW although the answer is much better than yours but it still doing what your code does.

Comment: yes, i did it tanks, but I want a single number with the count, with whereNotNull it gave me all counts from each element of the column

Comment: `$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->whereNotNull('inc_padre')
    ->count();`

Comment: with that I obtained a single count but it counts me all the rows including the nulls

Comment: `$ttg1 = DB::table('incidencias') ->whereNotNull('inc_padre') ->count();`    
`$ttg2 = DB::table('incidencias') ->whereNull('inc_padre') ->count();`    


`$ttg3 = DB::table('incidencias') ->count();`

Check this difference

Comment: with ttg1 and tt3 I obtained the the total count of the rowd which is 152, with ttg2 I obtained 0

Comment: Are you sure you have records where `inc_padre is Null`?

Comment: you are right, I dont have null elements, only empty rows.. so how could I count the elements

Comment: `->where('inc_padre', '!=', '')`

Comment: hey!! I have some elements that are repeated and I would like to take them in the same count.. is it posible?

Comment: `DB::table('incidencias')
    ->where('inc_padre', '!=', '')
    ->selectRaw('Count(DISTINCT(inc_padre)) as count')->get();`

Comment: `DB::table('incidencias')->where('inc_padre', '!=', '')
    ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT(inc_padre)'));`